# yii2 retype password not working

Tags: yii2-validation

I am try to implement retype password field in my registration form. but unfortunately i didn't work for me. please help me.

```
 public $repeatpassword;    
 public function rules()  {    

     [['Fname','Lname','username','email', 'password'], 'required'],
        [['password'],'string', 'min' => 3],
        [['repeatpassword'],'required'],
        ['repeatpassword', 'compare','compareAttribute'=>'password', 
                 'message'=>"Passwords don't match", 'on' => 'create']    
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
['repeatpassword', 'compare', 'compareAttribute' => 'password',
'message'=>"Passwords don't match"]
```